# Accessing nested ListView with QQmlContext

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to populate a QML ListView using a class that inherits QAbstractListModel. So far, I managed to create this using the QT Documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html), under the "QAbstractItemModel subclass" section:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <QQmlContext>
#include "gamemodel.h"  

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    GameModel model;    //A class similar to AnimalModel in Qt Documentation.
                        //It contains a QList of Objects, each having 2 QString
                        //members (title and genre).

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    model.readFile("c:/somePath/XML_G.xml"); //Initializing GameModel QList member 
                                             //using an XML file

    QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", &model);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window
{
    id: win
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    ListView
    {
        id: myList
        width: parent.width
        height: 50

        clip: true
        spacing: 5
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        model: myModel
        delegate:
        Rectangle
        {
            width: 150
            height: 20
            color: "#2255ff"

            Text
            {
                text: gameTitle + " " + genre
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Up to this point, my code works. However, if I try to change my *main.qml* file like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window
{
    id: win
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item    //ListView is now nested in this Item
    {

        ListView
        {
            id: myList
            width: parent.width
            height: 50

            clip: true
            spacing: 5
            orientation: ListView.Horizontal
            model: myModel
            delegate:
            Rectangle
            {
                width: 150
                height: 20
                color: "#2255ff"

                Text
                {
                    text: gameTitle + " " + genre
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

I end up being unable to set my model using *ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", &model)*;. From what little I can gather from the Qt Documentation (although I am most likely wrong), QQmlContext acts like a scope for the QML file. Thinking that, I tried changing this:

```
QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();
```

to this:

```
QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext()->findChild<QQmlContext*>("list");
```

As well as setting my Item's *objectName* property to "list". Obviously, that failed, and it also caused a crash. Since my experience with QML is limited to the Qt Docs, I have been unsuccessful at finding a workaround. Is a solution using QQmlContext possible, or do I have to use QObject? If so, what would the QObject equivalent of *ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", &model)* be?

Comment: Try doing   QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", &model); before engine.load(). Eg right after you define your model before you load the view.

Comment: My code above works normally. What I want to do is access a ListView nested in another Item, which is where I am currently stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the `setContextProperty()` call is basically the "identifier" of the object, like the `id` property on the QML side.

You need to set that before accessing it in QML, otherwise it is unknown at the time of usage.

So you don't need any other call, but you need to do it before you load QML that needs it.

Just move it before the `engine.load(...)` line in your `main.cpp`

Comment: What you say is indeed true. Whenever I run my program, I get a message that myModlel is undefined. However, that only happens in the QML file. As soon as my c++ code gets executed, the program continues running normally, and the list is shown as expected. I moved my `engine.load` before calling `setContextProperty()` on purpose, to see how long it takes for my XML to load. My issue however lies not in my code not working in general, but in making `setContextProperty()` find a ListView that is nested in another Item (i.e. a ListView that is not on the root level).

Answer (score 0):

OK, apparently my problem was in my QML file. In my code, I setup my ListView like this:

`width: parent.width`

However, when I added an Item as the parent of my ListView, I forgot to set an initial width for my Item, thus turning ListView's width to 0. After I set an initial width for my Item, everything works as expected again.